# User Name of document using VBA

Tags: vba, string, ms-word, comments, usernametoken

I tried to find the user name of the word document using VBA and tried to compare it with Author of the specified comment, If they are same notify me else no.

I have written code which is as

```
Dim oComment as Comment
Set oComment = ActiveDocument.Comments.Item(1)

Dim UserName As Application
Dim Author As Comment
Set UserName = Application.UserName
Set Author = oComment.Contact

Dim UN, AU As Strings

Set UN = CStr(UserName)
Set AU = CStr(Author)

If Not (UN Is AU) Then
If (oComment.Ancestor Is Nothing) Then
    MsgBox (ActiveDocument.Comments(LatestCommentIndex).Contact & " has added a new comment")
```

If I try to run it, it said Type mistach on the line
UserName = Application.UserName

Anybody has a workaround it?

Comment: `If UN <> AU Then` ? And `Dim UserName As String`, `UserName = Application.UserName`. You only use `Set` statement if you are trying to assign Object variable.

Answer (score 1):

"Application" is a global object, you don't need to initialize it, "Username" is a property of type String, so you will have the following code:

```
dim sUserName as string

let sUserName = Application.UserName

debug.print sUsername
```

Furthermore: to assign a value to a string variable, don't use "Set" but "Let" (which you can ommit at all: UN = sUserName, no casting, no special coomand)